# Repeat a function in javascript for "n" times to download text in parts

Tags: javascript, html, repeat

I would like to download text in parts and add it to a file "foobar" by repeating the download and write function from "data1" to "datan" where n is the last piece of the text.

This needs to be done as the text file is too big to be written directly into "foobar".

My current solution (snippet) is:

```
var data1 = "AAAAA";
var data2 = "BBBBB";

....

path += '/foobar';

....

downloadfunction(['echo "'+data1+'" >> '+path]);
downloadfunction(['echo "'+data2+'" >> '+path]);
```

The code works, but my main issue is with the last two lines. Is there a way to make the code more elegant by repeating "downloadfunction" from "data1" to datan"? "n" is a known, but large, number.

Answer (score 1):

Put the data in an array, then you can loop and modify your function to take `data` and `path` as arguments:

```
var data = ['AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCC'];
function download(data, path){
  save("echo " + data + " >> " + path);
}
...
path += '/foobar';
...
data.forEach(function(d){
  download(d, path);
});
```